# Algebra rearrangment (solving for $\theta_4$).

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$
\frac{d}{a}\cos\theta_4-\frac{d}{c}\cos\theta_2+
\frac{a^2-b^2+c^2+d^2}{2ac}=\cos(\theta_2-\theta_4)
$$

*Is it possible to rearrange this equation above to find the angle of $\theta_4$?*

I am having trouble trying to get $\theta_4$ out of the bracket on the RHS and collecting both the $\theta_4$'s together!?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can write the equation you have as $$d\cos \theta_4 - a \cos (\theta_2 - \theta_4) = B \to (d - a\cos\theta_2) \cos\theta_4 - a\sin \theta_2 \sin \theta_4 = B$$  which can be put in the form $$\cos(\theta_4 - \phi) =\frac B{\sqrt{(d - a\cos\theta_2)^2+a^2\sin^2 \theta_2}}  $$ and solved for $\theta_4.$